# Testing Log Messages Created by Slf4j Without Using Log4J

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, logback, slf4j

I want to test a method whether it's creating correct logs or not. My class looks like this:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.slf4j.Marker;
import org.slf4j.MarkerFactory;

class EventLogHandler {
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EventLogHandler.class);
    private final Marker eventMarker = MarkerFactory.getMarker("EVENT");

    public void handle(final Event event) {
        final String log = SomeOtherClass.createLog(event);
        logger.info(eventMarker, log);
    }
}
```

I've seen some examples/solutions for testing logs but all of them are using Log4j, which we are not using in the project. I can only use Log4j2 of spring-boot, Slf4j and Logback classic.
How can I test that handle(...) method with my existing dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the current implementation you cannot test/verify the invocations on `logger` without engaging a logging system and asserting on its output e.g. introduce logback and configure it with a stdout appender and capture stdout and assert against it etc.

In order to test your class without doing any of that you have to get your hands on the `logger` instance in use in `EventLogHandler`. The current implementation makes this difficult by constructing the `logger` like this:

```
private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EventLogHandler.class);
```

A common approach to testing in this scenario is to refactor the creation of logger in such a way that you can inject a mocked instance into `EventLogHandler` when running your tests. For example:

```
class EventLogHandler {
    private final Marker eventMarker = MarkerFactory.getMarker("EVENT");
    private final Logger logger;

    public EventLogHandler() {
        this(LoggerFactory.getLogger(EventLogHandler.class));
    }

    // probably only used by your test case
    public EventLogHandler(Logger logger) {
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    public void handle(final Event event) {
        logger.info(eventMarker, log);
    }
}
```

Then test it like so:

```
@Test
public void someTest() {
    Logger logger = Mockito.mock(Logger.class);
    EventLogHandler sut = new EventLogHandler(logger);

    sut.handle(event);

    // verify that the right state is extracted from the given event and that the correct marker is used
    Mockito.verify(logger).info(..., ...);
}
```

A less common alternative would be to use Powermock to allow you to mock this call: `LoggerFactory.getLogger(EventLogHandler.class);` and then use Mockito to verify calls onto it in the same way as is shown above..

Comment: Is it a good approach to change Logger to non-final ( because I still need to keep LoggerFactory.getLogger() ) and adding a constructor to only test a method?

Comment: Logger is still final, since it is always set via a constructor. The answer to the other part of your question - "adding a constructor to only test a method" - is: it depends, it's a valid approach to testing. It's a way of designing a class such that it is **testable**. If you don't want to do that then you could consider the other approach of using Powermock to mock the construction of Logger inside EventLogHandler.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see the default constructor, so it's final, you're right.
For the other question, I forgot to add where the log parameter is coming from, it was coming from an objectMapper as string. Because this logic was private in the EventLogHandler, I wasn't able to test the output. Instead, I moved this logic to another class to make it testable.